# Binding value is not updating on entry control from other xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding, xamarin-binding

I have an entry control in my XAML where I set the initial value on page appear through data binding. Initially the value is appearing but when I am updating it from another view model it is not getting updated on UI.

Below is the XAML code and XAML.CS

```
        <ListView
        x:Name="workList"
        Grid.Row="2"
        SeparatorColor="{DynamicResource AccentColor}"
        ItemsSource="{ Binding WorkItems }"                   
        Margin="5"
        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
        RowHeight="440"
        SeparatorVisibility="Default"
        SelectionMode="None"
        HasUnevenRows="False">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <local:LoadItemPutawayTemplate />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>


 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup- 
         compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="Sanipex.LoadItemPutawayTemplate">

<Grid
    RowSpacing="0"
    Padding="0"
    Margin="0,10,0,0"
    >

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition
            Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


            <Entry
                x:Name="OverrideLoc"
                 Grid.Row="0"
                TextColor="Black"
                WidthRequest="110"
                Text="{Binding toLocation}"
                grial:EntryProperties.BorderCornerRadius="10"
                grial:EntryProperties.BorderStyle="RoundRect"
                grial:EntryProperties.BorderColor="Black"
                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                Focused="OverrideLoc_Focused"
                TextChanged="OverrideLoc_TextChanged"
                grial:EntryProperties.HorizontalPadding="5"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                PlaceholderColor="Black"
                FontSize="20"/>


    </Grid>
```

```
public partial class ItemPutAway : ContentPage
{
    private static ItemPutAwayViewModel obj;
    public ItemPutAway()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        obj = new ItemPutAwayViewModel();
        BindingContext = obj;
    }

    public static ItemPutAwayViewModel itemPutAwayViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return obj;
        }
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        obj.LoadData();
    }
}
```

Below is my first view model code

```
public class ItemPutAwayViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private IList<WorkItem> workItems;
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  public string ltoLocation;

   public string toLocation
    {
        get => ltoLocation;
        set
        {
            ltoLocation = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(toLocation));
        }
    }

    public IList<WorkItem> WorkItems
    {
        get => workItems;
        set
        {
            workItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(WorkItems));
        }
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        WorkItems = App.dataManager.GetItemPutAwayWorks();
    }

    public void setLocation(string _location)
    {
        toLocation = _location;
    }

     protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the code through which I am trying to update the toLocation binding value to different value from another XAML page as below:

```
public partial class AvailableLocationsPopUp : PopupPage
{
    private static AvailableLocationViewModel obj;


    public AvailableLocationsPopUp(WorkItem _workItem)
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        obj = new AvailableLocationViewModel(gWorkItem.itemid);
        BindingContext = obj;
    }

    private void OnClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
    }

    private void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        Location content = e.Item as Location;

        ItemPutAway.itemPutAwayViewModel.setLocation("ABC-XYZ");

        PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();

    }
}
```

Comment: How come you have 2 viewmodels in the same page? Please provide a complete sample, or else it is difficult to analyze the problem

Comment: Sorry actually i am updating from another Xaml page the binding value, I have updated the code

Comment: Again, how are you acessing ItemPutAway in your PopupPage?

Comment: ItemPutAway is public XAML page and there I have created static method to get ItemPutAwayViewModel object

Comment: calling setLocation() updates the item's backing store WITHOUT calling PropertyChanged.  This is precisely the wrong thing to do if you want the UI to update.  Use the property setter instead

Comment: Jason, Can you give me an example please

Comment: This is a weird way of doing it, but ideally it should work. I'd suggest trying out using `MessagingCenter`, also decouples viewmodels and removes statics!

Comment: I may have misread it, you are using an extremely confusing naming convention for your properties

Comment: My value is being updated but when i scroll down the list and come back

Comment: @Zeeshanshaikh Try to set the value directly: `ItemPutAway.itemPutAwayViewModel.toLocation = "ABC-XYZ";`

Comment: I tried this thing as well but not updating on UI, but if i scroll down and come again it gets updated

Comment: Which version of Xamarin.forms are you using? Try to update to the latest.

Comment: I updated to latest one still its same

Comment: Can you share your code of the listView? I need to test the code to find the cause.

Comment: I have updated the code please check

Comment: While it works well on my side, how do you initialize WorkItems? Can you share a sample with this problem.

Comment: I am doing it in OnAppearing method of ItemPutAway , code is updated again to show you how I am binding the workItems. The issue is its getting updated in binding but not on UI.

Comment: @Zeeshanshaikh Have you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on the model `WorkItem` ?

Comment: @Jack can you check code under class ItemPutAwayViewModel, this is what I have done for property change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198162/discussion-between-jack-hua-msft-and-zeeshan-shaikh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the discussion, you have to also implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface of the class `WorkItem`.

Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in ItemPutAwayViewModel will only help for changes in the `WorkItems`(like add or remove one WorkItem), not the changes inside the `WorkItem`.

So, the code should be:

```
public class WorkItem : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{ 
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 

    private string _toLocation; 

    public string toLocation 
    { 
    get => _toLocation; 
    set 
        { 
          _toLocation = value; 
          NotifyPropertyChanged(); 
        } 
    } 

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") 
    { 
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); 
    } 

}
```

Comment: Hi Jack, I am facing problem now on WorkItem, I am adding new items to workItem but UI doesnt show until I go back and come again. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Please open a new thread and add your code there then I can check it for you.

Comment: I Opened a new one

Comment: Did you call NotifyPropertyChanged  in other properties like toLocation in your model Items?